# Python: zip 2 lists into a dictonary, del the duplicated keys but keep the values

Tags: python, list, multiset

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to zip 2 lists into a dictionary without losing the values of the duplicated keys and keep values as a list in the dictionary.

Example:

```
list1 = [0.43, -1.2, 50, -60.5, 50]

list2 = ['tree', 'cat', 'cat', 'tree', 'hat']
```

I'm trying to get the following outcome:

```
{'tree': [0.43, -60.5],'cat': [-1.2, 50],'hat': [50]}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault) method of the dictionary:

```
list1 = [0.43, -1.2, 50, -60.5, 50]
list2 = ['tree', 'cat', 'cat', 'tree', 'hat']
d = {}
for k, v in zip(list2, list1):
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Results:

```
>>> d
{'cat': [-1.2, 50], 'hat': [50], 'tree': [0.43, -60.5]}
```

Comment: How is this useful? It solves the problem as set but without a MVP we don't know what problems the OP actually had, if it was a homework question then they have an answer but it cheats them of a chance to learn..

Comment: This answer looks perfectly OK, and produces the desired outcome. I wonder why @Noelkd thinks the question is unclear.

Comment: [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Noelkd Well, the OP can learn how to solve this kind of problem using just one dictionary method.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by Mike Muller works perfectly well. An alternative, perhaps slightly more pythonic way would be to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the collections library:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [0.43, -1.2, 50, -60.5, 50]
list2 = ['tree', 'cat', 'cat', 'tree', 'hat']
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(list2, list1):
    d[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

just for completeness, this is how I would have do it in my early days programing

```
>>> list1 = [0.43, -1.2, 50, -60.5, 50]
>>> list2 = ['tree', 'cat', 'cat', 'tree', 'hat']
>>> result=dict()
>>> for k,v in zip(list2,list1):
        if k in result:
            result[k].append(v)
        else:
            result[k]=[v]


>>> result
{'hat': [50], 'tree': [0.43, -60.5], 'cat': [-1.2, 50]}
>>>
```